# Is it possible to use T-Mobile's 3G network on the airplane?

Tags: 3g, phone, cellular

So that I can go online?
Does it have signal in the air?

Comment: cleared up the tags

Comment: Also check out: http://superuser.com/questions/20634/what-do-cell-phones-cell-network-devices-potentially-interfere-with-on-airplanes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3G or HDSPA modems work pretty much the same way as cellular or mobile phones, so the following article will apply:

> Anyone who has flown on an airplane in
>   the past few years has heard the stern
>   warning from the flight attendant
>   about turning off cell phones and
>   other portable electronic devices.
>   Airlines warn that the signals from
>   cell phone transmissions can disrupt
>   navigation systems and pose a danger
>   to the aircraft. But is it even
>   possible to make cell phone calls
>   while in flight?
>
> **The simple answer**
>
> Following the terrorist attacks of
>   Sept. 11, 2001, news reports carried
>   stories of passengers phoning loved
>   ones in the minutes before the planes
>   crashed. Also, the Federal Aviation
>   Administration has conducted studies
>   indicating that despite the warnings
>   from flight attendants, an average of
>   one to four cell phone calls are made
>   from commercial flights in the United
>   States. Obviously, then, cell phones
>   can operate in flight, at least under
>   certain conditions.
>
> **How cell phones work**
>
> Cell phones are basically radios which
>   connect to a transceiver located on a
>   cell tower. Each tower covers a
>   certain area, or cell, hence the term
>   cell phone. When a phone moves from
>   one cell to another while in use, as
>   in the case when the caller is in a
>   car, the tower "hands off" the call to
>   the next tower. Cell phones can
>   typically connect to a tower up to 10
>   miles away.
>
> **The qualification**
>
> Towers, however, are configured to
>   connect to signals at ground level, so
>   while someone on the ground or in a
>   car may be able to connect to a tower
>   several miles away, that range is much
>   shorter when flying at 35,000 feet.
>   Also, a cell phone transmitting from a
>   high altitude may connect to several
>   towers at once, resulting in a
>   scrambled signal. And while the
>   cellular network can easily hand off
>   the call of someone traveling at 70
>   miles per hour, the task is much more
>   difficult when the caller is traveling
>   at 600 miles per hour.
>
> **The bottom line**
>
> While it might be possible to make a
>   cell phone call while in flight, the
>   bottom line is that chances are the
>   call quality won't be very good, if
>   you are able to connect at all. That
>   may be changing, though. Cell phone
>   companies are in the process of
>   developing equipment that can handle
>   calls from the air.
>
> **The downside**
>
> Unfortunately, allowing cell phone use
>   on airplanes will place airlines in
>   the position of finding ways to
>   control conflicts between passengers
>   because of inconsiderate cell phone
>   use. Congress is considering making
>   the ban on cell phone use permanent,
>   although the wireless industry is
>   resisting such a move. The airline
>   industry will most likely have to
>   develop a solution such as a "no-phone
>   section" in order to handle the
>   changes.

*[Source](http://www.ehow.com/about_5065930_cell-phones-work-airplanes.html)*

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you have to take the lower range of 3G into consideration. Also, if call quality is bad, 3G data connection will most likely fail completely. Nice explanation, though.

Comment: and i don't think it will be an option in the foreseeable future either. however, more and more airlines are to offer in-flight WiFi.

Answer (score 6):

According to airplane security regulations, you are not allowed to use cellular connections on an airplane.

As far as I know, it is technically possible to make phone calls (via the 2G network). 3G has lower range, so it could be impossible to connect from that altitude.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad citizenship to use cellular on a (standard) plane.  Because of your altitude, your phone tends to connect to multiple cells simultaneously and use very large amounts of bandwidth.  It may be technically possible but it's a violation of the rules of most airlines and it's not nice.  Is it really so bad to be off the grid for a few hours?

Comment: Also, if everyone in a commercial airliner left his cellphone turned on, the interference on the onboard instruments could cause major malfunctions.

Comment: People fear electromagnetic interference, but there is in fact no evidence whatsoever that it's real.